# Transporting doubles from one into another activity

Tags: java, android, double

I am trying to transport variables that I get through an `EditText` into the next activity. At first, I tried it with just one variable and it worked fine. But once I added the second activity, the app started to crash
once I tried it out. The app crashes when I try to press the button to get to the second activity.
Maybe you can find the mistake?

Following is my code.

**First Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button weiter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter1);
    weiter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText inputHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputheight);
            EditText inputlenght = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputlenght);

            Double height = Double.parseDouble(inputHeight.getText().toString());
            String Höhe = new Double(height).toString();

            Double lenght = Double.parseDouble(inputlenght.getText().toString());
            String Länge = new Double(lenght).toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("HöheName", Höhe);
            i.putExtra( "LängeName", Länge);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

**Second Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Höhe = intent.getExtras().getString("HöheName");
    String Länge = intent.getExtras().getString( "längeName");

    double höhe = Double.valueOf(Höhe);
    double länge = Double.valueOf(Länge);

    double längemalhöhe = höhe + länge;

    String ergebnis = new Double(längemalhöhe).toString();

    TextView Test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Test);

    Test.setText(ergebnis);

    Button weiter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter2);
    weiter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String Höhe = intent.getExtras().getString("HöheName");

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main3Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("HöheName", Höhe);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

**Third Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Höhe = intent.getExtras().getString("HöheName");

    TextView Test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ergebnis2);

    Test.setText(Höhe);
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
12-27 23:02:42.760 30997-30997/com.example.june.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.june.test, PID: 30997
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.june.test/com.example.june.test.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
        at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
        at com.example.june.test.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: can you provide the crash log?

Comment: yes, of course @DanielB.

Comment: A coding style tip, dont use ÅÄÖ in your variables. Stick to the english letters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's just a typo, but you have the line: `String Länge = intent.getExtras().getString( "längeName");` where `"längeName"` is not capital, however, you initially did this: `i.putExtra( "LängeName", Länge);` where  `"LängeName"` is capital. So the problem might be that the two strings aren't the same. When you try to do the following:

```
String Länge = intent.getExtras().getString( "längeName");
```

The string is initialized to `null` because there is no value assign to `"längeName"`, which can then lead to a `NullPointerException` if the string is attempted to be used.

Comment: @JuneR No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat, I see it says `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()` so your app crashes because a you are trying to use a String that is null. You need to check if the Strings you are working with are not null it avoid these crashes.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB. ! It tells me that     ´String Höhe = intent.getExtras().getString("HöheName");´ could cause that. But how can I change or check this?

Comment: **1.** You can debug your application, to check if the String is null.
**2.**  You can use the getString method with a default value, so in case it doesn't find a value for that key, it fallbacks to a default value you set, like this `getString("key","myDefaultValue");`

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
i.putExtra( "LängeName", Länge);
...
String Länge = intent.getExtras().getString( "längeName");
```

`LängeName` and `längeName` are different two keys.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the simple mistake pointed out by LAD, it is a good practice to store the string with a final modifier.

First Activity

```
final static String HOHE_NAME = "HöheName";
final static String LANGE_NAME = "LängeName";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


//....

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        i.putExtra(HOHE_NAME, Höhe);
        i.putExtra(LANGE_NAME, Länge);
        startActivity(i);
}
```

Second Activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String Höhe = intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.HOHE_NAME);
String Länge = intent.getExtras().getString(MainActivity.LANGE_NAME);
```